# Magento 2 - Frontend page giving 404 error page

Tags: magento2, module, 404

Hi I have created a module to view a form in the frontend. below is my code

/app/cod/TerrificMinds/Test/Block/Registration.php

```
<?php

namespace TerrificMinds\Test\Block;

class Registration extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
       }

    /**
     * Get form action URL for POST booking request
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormAction()
    {

        return '/test/registration/save';

    }
}
```

etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="test" frontName="test">
            <module name="TerrificMinds_Test"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="TerrificMinds_Test" setup_version="1.0.1" active="true"/>
</config>
```

view/frontend/layout/test_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="TerrificMinds\Test\Block\Registration" name="test" template="TerrificMinds_Test::registration.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

templates/registration.phtml

```
<h1>Booking page</h1>

<form action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" method="post">
    <input name="firstname" type="text">
    <input name="lastname" type="text">
    <input name="phone" type="text">
    <input name="bookingTime" type="date">
    <input type="submit" value="Send booking informations">
</form>
```

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'TerrificMinds_Test',
    __DIR__
);
```

Controller/Save.php

```
<?php

namespace TerrificMinds\Test\Controller\Registration;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Booking action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // 1. POST request : Get booking data
        $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if (!empty($post)) {
            // Retrieve your form data
            $firstname   = $post['firstname'];
            $lastname    = $post['lastname'];
            $phone       = $post['phone'];
            $bookingTime = $post['bookingTime'];

            // Doing-something with...

            // Display the succes form validation message
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Booking done !');

            // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('/companymodule/index/booking');

            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        // 2. GET request : Render the booking page 
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

When I try to hit mysite/test/index/index
its giving me 404 errorpage after setup upgrade,di compile and cache flushing.
What could be the error I am making.Please help.

Comment: Have you created controller as well? without controller it won't work.

Comment: i have updated qn with the controller . is this right way ?

Comment: Please update it with index controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have index controller at Vendor\Module\Controller\Index\Index.php and access it from test/index or test/index/index then you won't get any 404 error.
Let me know if you still face this issue.

Comment: You can mark it as solved if it worked for you. It'll help others.